# Finding matching records between 2 SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have one table that contains an item, and the primary supplier whom we purchased the item from.

```
Table 1
-------
item id
supplier id
```

I have another table that has records of all the times these items were purchased.

An item can be purchased from multiple suppliers, so an item can have multiple records in Table #2, with either the same supplier id or different supplier ids.

```
po #
item id
supplier id
date purchased
```

I am trying to find the last time an item was purchased for each record that is in Table 1.

This is the SQL code I've come up with, but it's not returning the results I'm expecting.

```
SELECT 
    K.item_ID, 
    MAX(PurchaseInfo.order_date) AS [Last Purchase Date],
    PurchaseInfo.po_no
FROM 
    Items K
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         order_date, supplier_id, po_no, item_id 
     FROM
         Purchases
     GROUP BY 
         order_date, supplier_id, po_no, item_id) AS PurchaseInfo ON PurchaseInfo.item_id = K.item_id 
                                                                  AND PurchaseInfo.supplier_id = K.supplier_id
GROUP BY 
    PurchaseInfo.order_date, K.item_id, PurchaseInfo.po_no
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

One approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select i.item_id, i.supplier_id,
       (select max(pi.order_date)
        from purchase_info pi 
        where pi.item_id = i.item_id and
              pi.supplier_id = i.supplier_id
       ) as most_recent_order_date
from items i;
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what  I need. How do also get the PO # that is also a field in the purchase_info table ?

Comment: @L.Levine . . . If you are using a database that supports lateral joins (sometimes introduced using `apply`), then you would do that.  Otherwise, you can use another correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by  for K.item_id,PurchaseInfo.po_no only (and not for PurchaseInfo.order_date otherwsie you don't find the max() )
and you shoudl also use DISTINCT instead of group by if you don't use aggreagtion function

```
SELECT 
   K.item_ID, 
   max(PurchaseInfo.order_date) as [Last Purchase Date],
   PurchaseInfo.po_no
FROM 
   Items K
   left outer join ( 
   select distinct order_date, supplier_id, po_no, item_id 
   from Purchases
  ) as  PurchaseInfo
ON  PurchaseInfo.item_id = K.item_id and PurchaseInfo.supplier_id = K.supplier_id
GROUP BY  K.item_ID ,  PurchaseInfo.po_no
```

Comment: This isn't returning the most recent purchase.

Comment: @L.Levine   try updated  your question add  a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select
  i.item_id,
  max(p.order_date) [Last Purchase Date]
from items i left join purchases p
on p.item_id = i.item_id
group by i.item_id
```

returns the last purchase date for each item. 
If you also want the column `po_no` then join it to `purchases`:

```
select t.*, p.po_no 
from (
  select
    i.item_id,
    max(p.order_date) [Last Purchase Date]
  from items i left join purchases p
  on p.item_id = i.item_id
  group by i.item_id
) t left join purchases p
on p.item_id = t.item_id and p.order_date = t.[Last Purchase Date]
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't include searching by a specific supplier.